# Why do we have login, non-login, interactive, and non-interactive bash shells?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

So the [bash man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) explain what login and interactive shells are:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or
>   one started with the --login option.
>
> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and
>   without the -c option whose standard input and error are both
>   connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started
>   with the -i option. PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is
>   interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this
>   state.

I think this means we can have 4 different types of shells:

- Interactive login shells,
- Non-interactive login shells,
- Interactive non-login shells,
- Non-interactive non-login shells

But why do we have interactive/non-interactive and login/non-login shells in the first place? Why the variety? What would we lose if we only had one type of shell?

Also when trying to determine if I am in a login shell by running `echo $-`, it outputs:

```
himBH
```

Some of these flags are explained [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html), but `h`, `H`, and `m` are not explained. Is there a place that describes all these flags?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are my thoughts on the different "types"of shells -- unfortunately I didn't witnessed the rise of the Un*x right from the beginning (I assume this concept is grown historically to a good extend), so please be critical.

- When I log into a system (nowadays via the graphical X login), there might be some tasks which should run once, e.g. establish a connection to some kind of server, present me a the today's todo list, autostart some commands, etc. This shouldn't happed every time I open up a new terminal. So there's a set of config files (`/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_login` and so on, refer to the manual for an accurate list) sourced only by *login* shells.
- Accordingly, to close the connections, kill some programs, run a backup script there is `~/.bash_logout` when the *login* shell exists.
- so, the "normal" shell I use in a terminal, shouldn't ba a *login* shell, but nevertheless should read my personal preferences from `~/.bashrc`, because I want my keybindings to interact with the shell -- hence this is an *interactive, non-login* shell.
- and last, but not least when  bash is used for scripting, neither of this is important. `bash` should start as fast as it can, i.e. shouldn't read any config files. This is a *non-interactive, non-login shell*.

So, my answer to your question *What would we lose if we only had one type of shell?* is in one word: "Flexibility."

---

The answer to your second question is easy:

`$-` lists the current set of options. These can either be set by command line parameters to `bash` or via the `set` builtin. So you have to look at two places in the manual:

- `OPTIONS` section:

  ```
  -i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
  ```
- `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section, subsection `set`:

  ```
  -h      Remember the location of commands as they are looked up for execution.  This is enabled by default.
  -m      Monitor  mode.  Job control is enabled.  This option is on by default for interactive shells on systems that sup‐
          port it (see JOB CONTROL above).  Background processes run in a separate process  group  and  a  line  containing
          their exit status is printed upon their completion.
  -B      The shell performs brace expansion (see Brace Expansion above).  This is on by default.
  -H      Enable !  style history substitution.  This option is on by default when the shell is interactive.
  ```

Comment: Woo I believe @mpy answer to OP's clearly formulated question is able to  succesfully desambigious some rather useful definition. About that: So, a non-login shell just is a *subset* of the login shell right?