# Unable to create a permanent alias in Mac OS

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, alias

In Linux I can well to add alias to bashrc and it will become a permanent alias. In Mac OS I tried to do the same thing:

**vim ~/.bashrc**

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH f  or scripting
alias prj="cd ~/Documents/projects"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

That being said, I got this:

```
$ alias
alias rvm-restart='rvm_reload_flag=1 source '\''/Users/alex/.rvm/scripts/rvm'\'''
```

So where is my `prj` alias? I rebooted the laptop but nothing has changed.

```
$ cat ~/.profile

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc

$ cat ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH f  or scripting
alias prj="cd ~/Documents/projects"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, `bash` only sources your `~/.bashrc` startup script file for interactive, **non-login** shells.
Usually, `bash` only sources your `~/.profile` startup script file for interactive **login** shells.
Usually, Terminal.app treats new terminal windows as interactive **login** shells.
So in normal circumstances, only your `~/.profile` gets read and executed; your `~/.bashrc` never gets read and executed.

To solve this, I usually create the shell startup script named `~/.profile` (if it doesn't already exist) and I add the following command to that file so that it checks to see if the `~/.bashrc` file exists, and it *sources* it (reads it in and executes it within the current shell process, not subshell) if it exists:

```
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

**Rephrasing as requested:**
Mac OS X's Terminal app usually runs your shell (`bash`) in "login" mode. When `bash` is run in login mode, it doesn't read/execute `~/.bashrc`. Instead, it reads and executes `~/.profile`. If you want to put things in your `~/.bashrc` and have them read and executed in every new Terminal window, you need to create a shell script file called `~/.profile`, and have that file contain a command that looks for your `~/.bashrc` and reads and executes it.

In case the verb "source" threw you off: "sourcing" a shell script file is when a shell (such as `bash`) reads shell commands from a file and runs those commands *in the current shell process, so they affect the environment of the current shell process*. Usually other shell script files you write are not *sourced*; instead, they are executed in a sub-shell (a separate instance or copy of `bash`), and they can't change anything in the environment of their parent shell (the main instance of `bash` that was started when you opened the new Terminal window).

To get a shell to source a script, you use the `source` command, which is built into the shell. A shortcut for the `source` command is `.` (yep, just a dot/period/full-stop character). In a previous version of this Answer, I used the `.` operator instead of the `source` command.

Comment: I didn't get it, can you re-phrase that?

Comment: but it works, nonetheless. but only when I run this command. when I open another shell "prj" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Alex Okay, try now.

Comment: thanks, but what is `... runs your shell (bash) in "login" mode` and what are the other modes exist and difference between them?

Comment: @Alex That's a topic that deserves its own Question. In fact it's already been asked and answered right here on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/657848/why-do-we-have-login-non-login-interactive-and-non-interactive-bash-shells

Comment: why not to add this alias to .profile instead of .bashrc?

Comment: @Alex You could, but you probably want this alias available every time you have an interactive shell (that is, every time you're interacting with the shell live from the keyboard), not just instances that happen to be marked as login shells. For example, if you opened a Terminal window, ran `emacs`, and then from there you `M-x shell` to do some work in the shell without leaving your `emacs` session, that shell that you're running from within emacs would be an interactive, non-login shell. If you want that alias available there, put it in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: actually, prj works only after `source ~/.profile`. I added your code to .profile. I wonder why?

Comment: @Alex to answer that, I'd have to know how you have your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` set up now, and whether you restarted your shell (closed and re-opened your Terminal window) since making the change.

Comment: what do you mean by setting up? I closed the Terminal.

Comment: @Alex I would need to know the contents of both files.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: @Alex Those files look good to me. I don't know why your alias isn't working.

Comment: what about `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: @Alex Good point. If you have a `~/.bash_profile`, `bash` will use that instead of `~/.profile`. So do you have it? Why? What does it contain? Same questions for `~/.bash_login`.

Comment: I have it and I put all that into it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open a new terminal window or run `source ~/.bashrc` after editing? The current terminal needs to be updated for the paths/aliases.

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
alias prj='cd ~'
:x
$ alias
$ alias rvm-restart='rvm_reload_flag=1 source '\''/Users/dx072/.rvm/scripts/rvm'\'''
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ alias
$ alias prj='cd ~'
  alias rvm-restart='rvm_reload_flag=1 source '\''/Users/dx072/.rvm/scripts/rvm'\'''
```

Comment: I said, "even after rebooting".

Comment: Right, so if the answer you accepted works, then this does as well. It's the same.