# Using homebrew's OpenSSH on OS X with ZSH

Tags: macos, zsh, openssh

I've installed the latest version of OpenSSH on OS X using homebrew. As per the instructions in [the formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/openssh.rb#L46-L66), I have edited the `org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist` file to point to `/usr/local/bin/ssh-agent`, and I have also added the following to my `.zshrc`:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
function cleanup {
    echo "Killing SSH-Agent"
    kill -9 $SSH_AGENT_PID
}
trap cleanup EXIT
```

This means however, if I have *n* terminal tabs open, I have *n* running `ssh-agent` processes. Is this necessary? Surely I only need one instance of ssh-agent running at any time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original instructions say to put these lines into your `.bash_profile`. This means they are only executed for *login* shells. A shell inside a normal terminal usually isn't a *login* shell, hence the *ssh-agnet* is started only once.

The corresponding rc file for zsh is `~/.zprofile`. So, put these lines not into `~/.zshrc`, but into `~/.zprofile`---*et voilà*.

If you want to know more about *login*, *interactive*, etc. shells, look into the shells' man pages, read [this answer on UnixSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43389/33390) or [my answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/659197/195224).

Comment: Moving this code from `.zshrc` to `.zprofile` simple means that opening a new terminal tab results in a new ssh-agent process being started. They are however, now no longer being stopped as the tabs are closed. Saying that, I am using iTerm2 and every new tab starts with `Last login...` on a new ttys

Comment: Is this behavior desired? If not, you should try to config your iTerm2 properly (do not invoke _zsh_ as `zsh -i`). Unfortunately I cannot help you with that as I'm not using OSX.

Comment: Changing iTerm from using login shell to a specific command of `/bin/zsh` seems to have worked.